Searching for information about personal blockchain
If I want to obtain information about personal blockchain, where should I look for it? Or could you provide me with some information about personal blockchain? Thank you！
I tried searching for some relevant research papers and used some search channels I know of, but I didn't find any relevant content. I hope to get some concepts of personal blockchain and understanding of its application scenarios.

I don't quite understand the question you are asking. What you would like to look for is information on Private Blockchains (what I understand you mean by personal)?
Only a few Blockchains are private, as is the case with Citigroup. And being private you should not be able to access their information beyond the centralized nodes of their network.
If you are also referring to the issue of personal identities on the Blockchain, I suggest you look into DID (Decentralized identity) (OasisLabs and Kilt Protocol have DIDs projects).
I hope I helped you, if not, let me know and we will look for the solution!

Thanks for your answer. What I mean by personal blockchain is not the same as private blockchain. As far as I know, private blockchains are mostly used in companies or organizations, and the number of nodes is not very small.

And I am more interested in personal blockchain, but it seems to be rarely mentioned. I learned from chatgpt that a personal blockchain is a blockchain managed and controlled by an individual or a small number of people. It can be used for personal data management, digital identity verification, etc. But I’m not sure whether this concept is correct, so I want to learn about personal blockchain from more channels.

Additionally, I'm a bit confused by the answer given by chatgpt mentioned above. If a blockchain is controlled by individuals, then there seems to be no need for a consensus mechanism, and there is no guarantee that the content on the blockchain is authentic and trustworthy. If a blockchain is managed by a few people, its security cannot seem to be guaranteed because the blockchain has too few nodes.
